# Flex 4 TLF and embedded font loaded as a module not working

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, tlf

this problem is really killing me so any help will be really great :)

I have a flex 4 application that loads a flex module. In this module I 'register' a bunch of fonts. I have a Spark textArea in this module that wants to use one of these fonts via its text flow which is created using:

```
textArea.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(htmlText, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
```

I 'register' the font using:

```
[Embed(source='/assets/fonts/book/HogarthScrD-Regular.ttf', embedAsCFF="true",fontName='HogarthScrD')] 
public static var _HogarthScrD:Class;
```

Where the html text is:

```
  var htmlText:String = "<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="HogarthScrD" SIZE="19" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"><B>My html Text</B></FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>";
```

I know the font 'HogarthScrD' exists as a debug on to the array of Font.enumerateFonts(); show me that 'HogarthScrD' is one of the element and is of type cff

I have read loads of documents around this and have failed to find a solution :( I read this artical: http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2010/03/flex_and_embedded_fonts.html 
tho I understand what it is saying I am not sure i know how to implement this... Even if someone can point me to the example will be useful!

I was thinking it was because it was importing from HTML text, so I just typed some text and used the emebedded font that doesn't work also.

Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: OK.. got somewhere. I can use that embedded font on a Spark Button by specifying the fontFamily. The font is just not applying to the imported text flow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got this to work. The problem was alot more trivial. Aren't they ever! The mere fact that the HTML was a string was causing the problem. If I use the same 'String' but as of type XML it works just fine..

so instead of what I have before just change the type to XML and get rid of the quotes!

```
 var htmlText:XML =<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="HogarthScrD" SIZE="19" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"><B>My html Text</B></FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>;
```