# Embed swf with TLF text in a Flash Builder 4.6 Project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

i'm trying to embed an swf file into a flash builder 4.6 project like this

```
[Embed(source="path/to/my.swf", symbol="my_symbol")]
public var MySymbolClass:Class;
```

Then i'm adding the symbol like this

```
var skin:Sprite = new MySymbolClass:Class() as Sprite;
addChild(skin);
```

The problem is it is not showing the texts in the embeded swf. I opened the source .fla and all the texts are TLF. If I change the text to classic text it works but I don't want to change all the texts as there are may of them.

I'm exporting the swf from flash cs6. I have already tried setting the default linkage as "Merged into code" and "runtime shared library (RSL)" at the ActionScript 3.0 settings but it does not work. If I chose "Preloaded SWF" it will cause an embed error in flash builder.

I'm using apache flex 4.12.1 SDK

Is there any solution to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if there are any embeded fonts in your swf

Check this URL.It may help you ..

[Flex 4 TLF and embedded font loaded as a module not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249625/flex-4-tlf-and-embedded-font-loaded-as-a-module-not-working)